# Javascript adding option values

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the javascript code below to add option values to a select field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#location").append($("<option></option>").val("Any Location").text("Any Location"));
$("#location").append($("<option></option>").val("Location 1").text("Location 1"));
$("#location").append($("<option></option>").val("Location 2").text("Location 2"));
</script>
```

This works ok but as my form is setup with PHP, I need to use the following code so that the selected value is retained in the select field when the results page is shown.

```
<option value="Any Location"<?php if(isset($_SESSION['location'])) { if($_SESSION['location'] == "Any Location") { echo "selected";} } ?> >Any Location</option>
```

Is it possible to somehow integrate the PHP SESSION code with the javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Yes the way you're proposing should work! PHP is parsed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as JSON:

```
var dataLocation = <?php 
                     if(isset($_SESSION['location'])) 
                     {
                       echo '{"location" : "'.$_SESSION['location'].'"}';
                     } 
                     else {
                       echo '{"location" : "Unknown"}';
                     } ?>
```

Now JavaScript will parse this as valid code and you can retrieve the location with: `dataLocation.location`;

If you execute this at the top of the script you can do this:

```
$("#location").append($("<option></option>").val("Any Location").text("Any Location"));
$("#location").append($("<option></option>").val("Location 1").text("Location 1"));
$("#location").append($("<option></option>").val("Location 2").text("Location 2"));

//updated version:
var selectElement = $("#location > option[value='"+dataLocation.location+"']");
if (selectElement)
{
    selectElement.attr("selected", true);
}
```

For this to work the value of the `option` needs to be identical to the location set in the `session`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this but now it doesn't display any option values in the select field? Do I need to use both bits of code together?

Comment: @MikeE, the first code bit shows how to set a variable from PHP into a JavaScript variable. The second is actually an example, but the need to be used both in that order.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a novice with Javascript - are you able to show this is a jfiddle? Thanks

Comment: @MikeE I can't do that since I cannot run PHP code in a fiddle. I can mimic it: http://jsfiddle.net/21xybxrh/1/